# Button isn't doing anything when clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to build a site that has three buttons, a Facebook Sharing one, a Twitter one, and another one that links to a video. They are classed as "facebook", "twitter", and "play". However, none of them go to the links that I had hoped. I had an external Javascript file but decided to just add everything in my HTML file based on advice. I really don't have much experience with JavaScript (just HTML/CSS) and all of the JavaScript was OpenSource code. Is there any minor error that I am completely neglecting or unaware of? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Soma - Share</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="share.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="mobile.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Support Soma with 3 Clicks</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <p id="welcome">
            <b>Hola, rockstar!</b><br /><br />We hope you're having an awesome day. You're here because we know you have influence. When you share something, people pay attention. So, please take a few seconds to spread the Soma love.
            <br /><br />
            <b>Thanks so much,</b>
            <br />
            Mike, Zach and the entire Soma Team
        </p>
        <div id="progress">
            <div class="percent">
                <div class="number">0%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="actions">
            <li>
                <h2>1. Share on Facebook</h2>
                <p>Share Soma with your friends</p>
                <button class="facebook"><span class="facebookSpan">f</span> Share</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>2. Post on Twitter</h2>
                <p>Hook your following up</p>
                <button class="twitter"><span class="twitterSpan"></span>Tweet</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>3. Watch our Video</h2>
                <p style = "font-size:13.4999px">Thank you in advance for backing Soma</p>
                <button class="play"><span class = "playSpan"></span>Play</button>          
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">&copy; Soma 2012</div>
    <script>




(function() {
var clicks = 0;
$('button').on('click', function() {
    clicks++;
    var percent = Math.min(Math.round(clicks / 3 * 100), 100);
    $('.percent').width(percent + '%');
    $('.number').text(percent + '%');
});


$('.facebook').on('click', function() {
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com');

    var w = 580, h = 300,
            left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2),
            top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);


        if ((screen.width < 480) || (screen.height < 480)) {
            window.open ('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://bit.ly/somawater', '', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
        } else {
            window.open ('http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://bit.ly/somawater', '', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);   
        }

});

$('.twitter').on('click', function() {
    var loc = encodeURIComponent('http://bit.ly/somawater'),
            title = "Beautifully innovative all-natural water filters by Soma — ",
            w = 580, h = 300,
            left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2),
            top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);

        window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=' + title + '&url=' + loc, '', 'height=' + h + ', width=' + w + ', top='+top +', left='+ left +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
});

$('.play').on('click', function() {
    window.location.href = "http://kck.st/TH0NAN";
});

});
    </script>   
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You asked same question again, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072874/why-are-my-buttons-not-doing-anything-when-clicked-on

Comment: Yeah I asked the same question again. Are you not allowed to? I tried to give more information in this one.

Comment: @user2677095 then make an update to the old post..

Comment: so you could do the same there itself. I am not saying you are not allowed.

Comment: just changed `(function() {` to `$(document).ready(function(){`. It is working. http://jsfiddle.net/zhZ5K/

Comment: I did edit that one but it got buried pretty down and no one was replying back to it! Thanks Suresh, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai So I changed (function() {to $(document).ready(function(){ in my HTML file but for some reason it's still not working. Do you have any other suggestions that could possibly fix this solution? Nothing is happening when buttons are clicked though as you said it works perfectly in your jsfiddle.net link.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out! It had to do with the line:   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>. I replaced it with: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and it somehow worked. Thanks for the help! And sorry...I'm not sure how to properly format code in the comment section.

Comment: @user2677095 thats fine.

Answer (score 4):

You're just missing some brackets

```
(function() {
    var clicks = 0;
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        ...
    });

    $('.facebook').on('click', function() {
        ...   
    });

    $('.twitter').on('click', function() {
        ...
    });

    $('.play').on('click', function() {
        ...
    });

})(); // <- Note the extra brackets
```

By placing your code inside `(function() { ... })()` you are creating an function expression and then immediately invoking it. This is known as an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression)

---

**Update**

Here is the code using jQuery's document.ready approach. Using this approach the IIFE described above is not required.

This approach waits until all the elements on the page have loaded before executing the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicks = 0;
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        ...
    });

    $('.facebook').on('click', function() {
        ...   
    });

    $('.twitter').on('click', function() {
        ...
    });

    $('.play').on('click', function() {
        ...
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, I added the extra brackets but that change my problem. Are IIFE's discouraged against? This was the general format of the open source code and I'm pretty unfamiliar with JavaScript. I googled my question but there wasn't much advice regarding when/whether it should be used. Thanks!

Comment: Wrapping code in an IIFE is **highly** recommended because it prevents pollution of the global scope (e.g. with your `clicks` variable). What is your new issue? Are your buttons working?

Comment: @user2677095: its always a good practice to bind event handlers after your DOM is loaded completely.which may not be the case when u use IIFE

Comment: @Runner agreed. In this case, the IIFE isn't really required. OP could just wrap in a document ready block: `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: I just changed it to a $(document).ready(function() { ... }); format but for some reason it didn't make a difference. Any other idea as to why it may not be working? I'm really confused as it seems like everything is done right.

Comment: @user2677095 I've updated the answer with the `$(document).ready` approach. I can't help you any more unless you tell me what's not working

Comment: The buttons for some reason aren't doing anything when clicked on. I thought it may be an issue with how JQuery was added? Did I do it right in that it's supposed to be like:    
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Okay I just figured it out!! It had to do with the line I just mentioned. Instead of what I wrote, I replaced it with: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and for some reason it worked. Do you have any idea why that change resulted in it to work?

Comment: @user2677095 Yes. That should work. You can try downloading it to the same location as your html page and reference it locally if you want

Comment: @user2677095 it should work either way. Starting the src with `//` is supposed to help when pages could be http or https. Glad it's working now though

Comment: And sorry...I'm not sure how to properly format code in the comment section.